# How to get Enum value statically?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, enums, json.net

I want to get the EnumMember's Value statically. It works if I pass fill out my model, as shown below.

**LibraryStatus Enum**

```
public enum LibraryStatus
{
    Watching, 
    Completed,
    [EnumMember(Value = "On Hold")]
    OnHold,
    Dropped,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Plan To Watch")]
    PlanToWatch
}
```

**Class**

```
public class LibraryListing
{
    ...
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public LibraryStatus LibraryStatus { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When I pass the Model to view:

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings {ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }));
```

**JSON Output**

```
[{"AnimeListId":2146,"LibraryStatus":"On Hold","AnimeAccountId":3},{"AnimeListId":2165,"LibraryStatus":"Plan To Watch","AnimeAccountId":3},{"AnimeListId":2145,"LibraryStatus":"Watching","AnimeAccountId":3},{"AnimeListId":2174,"LibraryStatus":"On Hold","AnimeAccountId":3},{"AnimeListId":2143,"LibraryStatus":"Watching","AnimeAccountId":3},{"AnimeListId":2171,"LibraryStatus":"Dropped","AnimeAccountId":3}]
```

Look at the "LibraryStatus" key, it has a value of "On Hold"

However, when I do a call like this:

```
var output = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LibraryStatus));
```

the output is:

```
[0] => "Watching",
[1] => "Completed",
[2] => "OnHold", *****
[3] => "Dropped",
[4] => "PlanToWatch" *****
```

I basically need the enum names statically. How can I get the output to match? Or better yet, anyone have a better method/suggestions? I basically need the output so I can filter the data on the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private List<String> GetEnumNames(Type enumType)
{
    return enumType.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Select(m => { 
        var attr = m.GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>();
        if (attr != null)
            return attr.Value;
        return m.Name;
    }).ToList();
}
```

Running:

```
var output = GetEnumNames(typeof(LibraryStatus));
output.Dump();
```

Gives me the output:

```
Watching 
Completed 
On Hold 
Dropped 
Plan To Watch
```